# Código Injetado

Tags: javascript, framework7

Utilizo o Framework7 e uso o código injetado via JavaScript. Preciso que quando o usuário clique em determinado botão na "Página Injetada" volte para a principal.

O `history.go(-1)` e o `window.history.back();` não funcionam por não estar no histórico as páginas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O próprio F7 tem essa função:

```
app.router.back(); //Volta para a página anterior.
```

ou

```
app.router.navigate('/'); //Volta para o index, configurado nas rotas.
```